# I am stuck on Mars, can't travel anywhere

Tags: tex-murphy-2

I'm on Mars while playing Tex Murphy 2: Martian Memorandum. The only places I can visit are the Casino and Lowell Percival. There seems to be no way for me to pass the pressure sensitive floor and lasers in Dick Castro's office in the Casino.

Having wasted a lot of time in the air vents of the casino, I glossed over [a walkthrough](http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcMm/MartianMem.htm) to see what I should be doing. It seems to state I should be traveling to a power plant, but this option is not available to me in the list.

**Am I stuck?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **you are stuck**. You missed a few things while still on earth which were essential to do before going to Mars, and there is no way to fly back.

Load the latest save game right before you flew to Mars. Before flying to Mars **ensure you have five locations to visit**, of which you already know Lowell Percival and the casino.

You can find the remaining three at the following locations:

> Power Plant (at Terraform), Dr. Lawrence Barkley (at Terraform), Aerobics Academy (outside, Rick Logan)